# Mosfet current control with PWM

Tags: arduino, mosfet, pwm

I am using a mosfet and an Arduino and I want to control the Source-Drain current of the mosfet by adjusting PWM to the Gate.

If I apply zero value to the PWM, the current doesn't stop (I checked the PWM output with voltmeter and it's zero volts). When I manually connect the gate to the ground with a wire, the current stops.

How can I stop the current with PWM output that connected to the gate?

Here's my circuit. I common all the grounds with wire and put mosfet and hall effect sensor on two separate breadboard.

Also, I'm powering the Arduino with a printer cable that's connected to my laptop.

[image: Schematic]

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Please add a schematic to show your circuit configuration. Please also capitalise your title and post properly for ease of reading and correct syntax as per site policy - see [Write to the best of your ability](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer) on the site's help pages.

Comment: Show the schematic and a **clear** picture of the physical implementation.  It's possible you've damaged or miswired the MOSFET.   **Also explain how you are measuring the current**.  Also try configuring the pin as a simple output driven low, not a PWM and see if you get a different result.

Comment: .... and don't forget to clearly show how and where power and Arduino grounds are connect

Comment: Connect a resistor - maybe 10k- between gate and source. That'll fix your problem.

Comment: With PWM set to zero, measure voltage from Arduino +5V to the MOSFET Gate. What do you get?

Comment: @BruceAbbott Nice floating gate test :)

Comment: sorry for my grammar and writing mistakes. @ChrisStratton I'm measuring the current with DC power(I mean that itself has an ampere meter)

Comment: @Kripacharya could you please explain your reason of doing that?

Comment: The glaring problem with your circuit is that you've interchanged the proper positions of the inductive load and the MOSFET.  Q1's source needs to be grounded, directly or at most through a small sense resistor.  Beware that some cheap bench supplies have truly nasty turn on and turn off behavior with huge voltage spikes.  Plus a MOSFET sitting on top of an inductor could easily result in exceeding the gate oxide's quite low maximum voltage rating.  You should rebuild the circuit with the FET and load in proper positions, a reverse catch diode across the load, and you may need a new FET.

Comment: @ChrisStratton thank you. I'll do that and will share you the result. but could you explain  why the position of the load is wrong and why the MOSFET 's source should be grounded directly?(I ask this for learning and increase my skills)

Comment: It would probably be worth reading up on MOSFETs and low side switching in general.  Your MOSFET is controlled by the gate-vs-source voltage.  With the source sitting on a resistive load, you'd not be able to really leverage a higher power supply, because you can't raise the gate voltage above the MCU's output voltage.  But with an inductive load, the source voltage would "bounce" making the situation even worse. Without looking at the data sheet, a typical MOSFET will be destroyed if it ever sees more than a 20 volt or so difference between gate and source. Source needs to match gate's ground

Comment: MOSFETs and other transistors  only know about the voltages between their terminals.  They don't know, or care, where we think "Ground" or "Zero volts" is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the source of your MOS-FET needs to be connected to the reference of the 5V supply of the arduino, your schematic does not show this connection.

without it the gate voltage is floating so it will be very unlikely to ensure turn off while floating.

You always apply voltage as a differential so a single connection, the gate needs the output, but also the source needs to be connected to the 5V reference.

Sadly, this is not a good design you do not want the reference of the Arduino to have an inductor leading to ground right after and not be connected to ground.

I have a couple ideas from the top of my head.

Re-design the circuit so the source goes to ground and you can connect the Arduino reference to source also

use a DC-DC converter to isolate the arduino from your 5V power line then there is no issue with connecting the source to the 5V reference.

Answer (score 1):

You may try this ?

Link : 
Potentiometer as MOSFET control + Arduino

https://classes.engineering.wustl.edu/ese205/core/index.php?title=Potentiometer_as_MOSFET_control_%2B_Arduino

Attach Image
[image]

after success, you may replace potentiometer with PWM.

Reference Link :

https://tutorial45.com/arduino-mosfet-project/

Comment: Welcome at electronics.SX. To give a good answer here you should probably replace the nice colorful picture with a real circuit diagram to make it easy to understand the circuit. Also you should eleborate a little bit more why you suggest this circuit. Link-only-answers are likely to be deleted due to there limited use for this platform.

Comment: Welcome as a general rule i would suggest when publishing an answer to anything, to read what you write and ask yourself whether you would understand it if you hadn't written it yourself, also to check your schematics (even if they are fritzing ones) if you look at the transistor (or regulator) at the bottom left you will see that it is floating